# How to generate a unique uuid inside a mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to generate a unique uuid from within mongodb aggregation pipeline but the id is always the same for all events.

```
$replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        {
          eventId: uuidv4(),
          // ...
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

Is there a workaround to get something like this working?

Comment: Looks like you have to run `UUID()` in a `forEach()` loop

Comment: The reason they are all the same is the `uuidv4()` call is executed on the client side and its result included in the query sent to the server.  I'm not aware of any operator to generate new data inside an aggregation pipeline

Comment: To make things worse it's actually on a view that is read only